# UIViewController custom transition keyboard does not disappear

Tags: uiviewcontroller, customization, uikeyboard, presentmodalviewcontroller

I'm presenting an UIViewController using a custom transition implementation:

```
JWModalController *modal = [[JWModalController alloc] init];

CGRect originalFrame = [[self view] convertRect:[[modal view] frame] toView:nil];

[[modal view] setFrame:CGRectZero];
[[self view] addSubview:[modal view]];

[self addChildViewController:modal];
[modal didMoveToParentViewController:self];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 animations:^{
    [[modal view] setFrame:originalFrame];
}];
```

This works great and i'm quite happy with the result.

BUT: When presenting a viewController the regular way (`[self presentViewController:modal completion:nil];`), the keyboard dismisses if a textfield is first responder.

When using my way, the keyboard does **not** dismiss.

Sure, I could easily keep track of the first responders or save the textField and call `-resignFirstResponder` manually... But I really want to know how to do it *the right way*.

Comment: I believe "keep track of the first responders or save the textField and call -resignFirstResponder manually" is the right way to do it.

Comment: Eventually "the right way" is not the best expression... I'm looking for the way, the usual `-presentViewController:completion:` method achieves it.